# Auto restart Apache on High server load [Vultr]

Tags: apache2

I want to Auto restart Apache on High server load. How to do it?

I use Ubuntu

Comment: Why would you need to restart Apache on high server load? This sounds like a misconfigured web server or a poorly-optimized website 

Comment: You *really* need to reoptimize your site or application or webserver stuff if your system is regularly hitting high load due to Apache  If the system is running on Vultr in the cloud, you may have to configure this type of monitoring on their end.